# Xamarin Forms - Webview is not showing up within my StackLayout

Tags: android, xamarin, webview, xamarin.android

why isn't the `WebView` showing ? I have tried `FillAndExpand` and `CenterAndExpand` , but it still not working!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views;assembly=MyApp"
             x:Class="MyApp.Pages.Main">
  <StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Start">
      <!-- top controls -->
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout x:Name="WebViewLayout" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
      <WebView Source="https://www.google.com/" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="End">
      <views:AdMobView WidthRequest="400" HeightRequest="50" />
    </StackLayout>
  </StackLayout>


</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the Vertical Options of the StackLayout (which holds the WebView) from CenterAndExpand to FillAndExpand and the WebView itself.

I hope this helps. :)

```
<StackLayout x:Name="WebViewLayout" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
     <WebView Source="https://www.google.com/" VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking the `WebView` out of the parent `StackLayout` and the change the outer most `StackLayout` to a `Grid`.

That being said, I think that might help solve the issue without doing that:

```
public override void OnAppearing()  {
    SizeChanged += (sender, e) => {
        WebViewItem.WidthRequest = Width;
        WebViewItem.HeightRequest = 200; //Or what ever
    }

    OnSizeChanged(null, null); //Make it run at least once
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't say exactly why but setting the VerticalOptions on the stack layout seemed to solve it for me. The following results in the web view being drawn:

```
var webView = new WebView();
webView.Source = "https://www.xamarin.com";
webView.MinimumWidthRequest = 200;
webView.MinimumHeightRequest = 200;
webView.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
webView.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;

var stackLayout = new StackLayout;
this.Content = stackLayout;
stackLayout.Children.Add(webView);
stackLayout.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
stackLayout.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
```

I admit the layout behavior for StackLayout is pretty confusing.